# Looking for help/validation on this foosball game database design

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I'm working with my coworkers on a fun side project of bringing our foosball table into the digital world. We've attached sensors to the table to keep track of the scoring, and we are adding the ability for players to sign-in when playing and we are going to keep track of some statistics. We've designed a database schema and are hoping to get some validation on what we've done, or clarification on what we need to change. Any input would be appreciated!

We plan to keep track of players, games, and play history. We mainly had the play history table as a way of keeping track of how many players were in a game (2 or 4). We also want to keep track of any series that the players play in, although not every game is a series.

[image: Foosball Database Design]

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your design, and I have a couple comments:

- Players

  - TotalTimedPlayed, GameWins, TotalGamesPlayed, SeriesWins, TotalPoints
    and Shutouts can all be calculated from the data.
  - I do not like to store data you can obtain from queries in tables,
    since these have a tendency to get desynchronized with time.
- Games

  - No need for a "Single" boolean value anymore, I take for granted this
    was to identify games with only one player?
  - WinMargin and Winner, again calculatable.
- Series

  - NumGames can be calculated.

---

So I desined the following schema.
[image]

---

Why teams?

- if you have 4 players, they play 2 by 2.  With only 2 players, you have single players teams.
- My first model linked players directly to games, but it proved difficult to calculate GameWins.  Ex. with 4 players, I could not declare the user with the highest score a winner, since there were 2 users with that same score. Easier to declare a team a winner.
- if players play together often, they can accumulate team statistics.
- BUT you could do without, and link Players to Games directly.It would make some queries more complex however.

---

To calculate the different values:

- **TotalTimePlayed**: Games.EndTime - Games.StartTime for games where the teams include player X.
- **GameWins**: count(Games) for games where the team(s) of player X had a higher score than the other team.
- **TotalGamesPlayed**: count(Games) for games where the team(s) of player X is associated to a game.
- **SeriesWins**: count(Games) associated to Series Y, where the team(s) of player X had a higher score than the other team.
- **TotalPoints**: sum(Score) from games where the team(s) of player X participated.
- **Shutouts**: count(Games) where the team(s) of player X had a score > 0 and the other team had a score == 0.
- **NumGames**: count(Series_has_Games) where GameId = X

Have fun!